# Using Java to communicate to a USB device from browser

Tags: usb, webusb

We have a java web application and now we have a new request: the client wants to communicate with their USB device using our application. They plug the device into their PCs, open a page of our web application and the page will communicate with the device to get some input. Communication here means reading some input from the device. This should be support on every script supported browser. Can someone give me a guide or a link that tells me how to do it? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebUSB API](https://github.com/WICG/webusb) to communicate with USB devices in the Web app. However, WebUSB is only implemented in Chromium.